# Converting input from editText to text output using predefined matrix

Tags: java, android

Sorry for such a basic question! but its Friday and my mind has given up for the week.

I am writing an additional section into an app which needs to take a user input, in text format, restrict the input to 16 characters, and only allow certain letters.

It then needs to output that as a string of numbers, related to those letters.

i.e., where a C is input, the output for that character needs to be 22, where a space is input, the output needs to be 29, etc

Help! I'm stuck on which direction to take!

I'm not looking for the code writing, just a head start on the best approach :)

I was going to look at a HashMap

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @j_b So far I have set a HashMap to the required characters, the problem I am having so far is I am only getting the output from the final character in the string.

Comment: I've just realised, it's not even Friday! wow my mind has gone this week! 

Comment: Edit your question to include a code block containing your code so far.  Also include sample inputs and expected outputs